# Magento 2 – Item with the same ID already exists

Tags: magento2, database, orders, magento2.4, products

I am getting this error when try to open product Report. Anyone can help me on this How to i can fix this issue ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your report result collection query, may be it would return multiple records with same id (primary key entity_id).

Use group by for id ( primary key Id) in your result collection.

Ex:

```
getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');

$collection->getSelect()->group('TABLE_NAME.FIELD_NAME')
```

Comment: can you help me with full query ?

Comment: Find your result collection.

Comment: is it order collection or product collection?

Comment: actually this is product reporting - But error is showing something regarding Orders Collections

Comment: get query from collection with "getselect" or PrintLogQuery .  and check it in database .
If you find multiple duplicate records then only use group by function your problem would be resolved.